# Angular Material 14 - common-behaviors folder not found after updating

Tags: angular, angular-material

After updating to Angular 14, the following code snippet is not working anymore.

Looks like common-behaviors folder is not being found.

Is there any other solution than creating myself the HasElementRef interface?

```
import { HasElementRef } from '@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/color'

export class MyClass implements HasElementRef {
  constructor(public _elementRef: ElementRef) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd be using that interface to begin with - it's an internal interface from what I can see with just a single property

```js
/** @docs-private */
export interface HasElementRef {
  _elementRef: ElementRef;
}
```

- https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/core/common-behaviors/color.ts

Copy it and use your version if needs be

Comment: Thank you Drenai. Yes, I ended up copying it on my project. The thing is it was available before, so I wanted to keep just referencing it as it has historically been.